# How do you use buefy's b-taginput in a custom component so that it works like v-model, It is only working one way binding?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I'm new to vue and decided to try out buefy for some useful components.

To try and keep my code organized I'm trying to make a custom component using the **b-taginput**.
I have it so that the component loads with the tags in someArrayofTags, but when I'm typing into the b-taginput, it does not add new tags into someArrayofTags. Hence I lose the two-way binding / updating. I would like to know where I am going wrong and how I could adjust this.

I'm not too well versed to understand how they have implemented it, but i do see that it is composed of autocomplete and b-tags https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/src/components/taginput/Taginput.vue

I'm trying to use the custom component as such
`<mytaglist v-model="someArrayofTags"></mytaglist>`

I know v-model is just v-bind on value and @input events. My code is below.

```
<template>
  <b-field label="tag inputs">
    <b-taginput
      :value="value"
      @input=someMethod($event.target.value)
      size="is-small"
      ref="ti"
    >
      <template slot="selected" slot-scope="value">
        <b-tag
          v-for="(tag, index) in value.tags"
          :key="index"
          :type="getType(tag)"
          rounded
          :tabstop="false"
          ellipsis
          closable
          @close="$refs.ti.removeTag(index, $event)"
        >
          {{ tag }}
        </b-tag>
      </template>
    </b-taginput></b-field
  >
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data() {
    return {
        normal: ["wnl","clear"]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    someMethod(tags) {
        alert(tags)
        this.$emit("input", tags)
    },
    getType(tag) {
      if (this.normal.includes(tag)) {
        return "is-danger";
      } else {
        return "is-success";
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After going through the source for buefy, I found that I could **watch** and update the values based on a v-model within the new component.

The code below works for me, but if anyone could provide a better solution I will leave it open.

```
<template>
  <b-field label="tag inputs">
    <b-taginput
      v-model="newValue"
      size="is-large"
      ref="ti"
    >
      <template slot="selected" slot-scope="value">
        <b-tag
          v-for="(tag, index) in value.tags"
          :key="index"
          :type="getType(tag)"
          rounded
          :tabstop="false"
          ellipsis
          closable
          @close="$refs.ti.removeTag(index, $event)"
        >
          {{ tag }}
        </b-tag>
      </template>
    </b-taginput></b-field
  >
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data() {
    return {
        normal: ["wnl","clear","deep & quiet"],
        newValue: this.value
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getType(tag) {
      if (this.normal.includes(tag)) {
        return "is-danger";
      } else {
        return "is-success";
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
      newValue(value) {
          this.$emit('input', value)
      },
      value(value) {
          this.newValue = value
      }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```